# (MSM) 'View Site' CP Link

Tags: multi-site-manager

Using MSM with EE v2.9.0

My 'View site' button in the top right hand corner of the control panel only links to the default_site.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a config setting that could be conflicting and causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a bug, but also kinda by design. When you setup secondary sites in the control panel, you never actually enter a Site URL for your those sites, so the control panel never actually *knows* what your other site URLs are.

Your *templates* know, because when you add your custom MSM config variables to your secondary sites' you set it explicitly via `$assign_to_config['site_url']` - but again, the CP doesn't load this file or even know it exists.

So, the View Site link is working "correctly", but it's bad UI. You may want to [file a bug with EllisLab](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, was worried it was a residual config setting conflicting with it.